# bash for-loop: do something only after the first iteration

Tags: bash

```
for f in "$@"
do
  echo     # I'd like to skip this the first time
  echo $f
  print_info_about $f
done
```

This fragment of a bash script accepts some filenames and prints each one and some info about it, with a blank line between them.
What's a clean way to avoid the unnecessary initial blank line?
Equivalently, what's a clean way to `echo` after each iteration except the last?

Cleaner than splitting off the first (or last) item in `$@` and using an extra call to `print_info_about`.
Ideally, as clean as Ruby accumulating everything into an array of strings and then `.join("\n")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
separator=''
for f
do
  printf "$separator"
  separator='\n'
  echo "$f"
  print_info_about "$f"
done
```

This will call `separator='\n'` in vain during the 2nd iteration and later. But assignment is internal to the shell and therefore fast, so performance should not suffer.

The question is tagged `bash` so I [fixed your quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) (unquoted variables behave well in `zsh`). Sole `for f` is equivalent to `for f in "$@"`.

---

Note the above solution is not a general way to "do something only after the first iteration". It's tailored to your specific "something" (printing a blank line as separator).

The following generalized approach checks if the variable is not empty and runs arbitrary `do_something` conditionally.

```sh
marker=''
for f
do
  if [ "$marker" ]; then
    do_something
  fi
  marker=whatever
  print_info_about "$f"
done
```

Comment: This works even without the initial `separator=''` :-)

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Not if you have two fragments of code like this in a script and `separator` from the first one survives to the second.

Comment: It's always good practice to initialize variables in bash, to avoid them being inherited from the environment if the caller happens to `export` the same variable for some other purpose...

Comment: One more golf: `printf "$separator$f"` omits the `echo`.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune And doesn't print the trailing newlline. Additionally `printf` interprets expanded `$separator$f` as format. The most robust form that adds the newline and interprets neither `$separator` nor `$f` as format would be `printf '%s%s\n' "$separator" "$f"`. In my code the expanded `$separator` is interpreted as format but it never contains anything that may not be treated literally. On the other hand `$separator$f` is arbitrary. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519315/108618).

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with an extra blank line *after the last item*, you could do:

```bsh
for f in "$@"; do
    printf '%s\n%s\n\n' "$f" "$(print_info_about "$f")"
done
```